# How to solve $y''+9y = e^t \cos{2t}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y''+9y = e^t \cos{2t}$

Normally, if it was just in the form: $$y''+y'+y=0$$ I know how to solve it, but the extra term is confusing me!

The question also specifies the initial conditions $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=1$

Please help!

Comment: Have you learn how to solve inhomogeneous equations?

Answer (score 1):

$$e^t \cos(t) = \dfrac{1}{2} e^{(1+i)t} + \dfrac{1}{2} e^{(1-i)t}$$

Look for a particular solution of the form 
$y = a e^{(1+i)t} + b e^{(1-i)t}$
where $a$ and $b$ are complex numbers.

Comment: It's not as simple as equating coefficients? Sorry, this just seems rather alien to me!

Comment: It is quite simple if you know how to use complex numbers.  Slightly more complicated without them: look for a solution of the form $c_1 e^t \cos(t) + c_2 e^t \sin(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

First, solve the homogeneous equation:

$$ y'' + 9y = 0 $$

which would give $y = C_1 \sin(3x) + C_2 \cos(3x) $

And use variation of parameters or method of undetermined coefficients to find the particular solution.

Comment: I know how to solve the homogeneous equation, but what is this variation of parameters that you speak of?

Comment: Please @TheGreatDuck could you please explain it in a bit more detail -- I am not so good at calculus!